# Why I am unable to get output while using BufferedWriter?

Tags: java, io, bufferedwriter

I am unable to get the output while using `BufferedWriter`. From my point of view it will show

```
d

aei

durga
```

[where i posted why no output particularly]

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class BufferedWriterDemo
{
    public static void main(String s[])throws Exception
    {
        //char b='a';
        File f=new File("abc.txt");
        //f.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f);
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(100);
        bw.newLine();
        char ch1[]={'a','e','i'};
        bw.write(ch1);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("durga");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line=br.readLine();
        while(line!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            line=br.readLine();
        }
        bw.flush();
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

Output Shown

//i didnt got anything

Comment: Because a BufferedWriter doesn't actually write anything until you write 8 kilobytes, or flush it, or close it? (That's the *entire point* of BufferedWriter)

Comment: As an aside, your variable names are *very* confusing. You've used `br` for a Buffered**Writer** and `bw` for a Buffered**Reader** and the same for file readers/writers. I would expect them to be the other way round, with a `w` suffix for writer and an `r` suffix for reader...

Comment: @immibas I didn't understood can u explain in detail a little bit Do  i need to add more data into the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After:

```
bw.write("durga");
```

- Try doing:

  ```
  bw.flush();
  ```

  so it could write the data into the file, *or*
- close the file handle there as you are done writing to the file.

As the name suggest, it buffers the data: once buffer is full, it pushes through to file in your example. But you are just writing few data, so i would suggest either close or flush your stream.